# Why has my getBalance function stopped working?

Tags: solidity, remix

I put a getBalance function for a simulated Dex.sol contract and it was working before but now it just returns 0 when i try the function in sol.. even after sending a token to test.

I am sending 1 USDC to the Dex.sol contract (0x9F2D378b2778130e59C04A09A4B76dFF41878Fbf) that is deployed on the goerli network and you can see the 1 USDC being transferred into the contract (https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x9F2D378b2778130e59C04A09A4B76dFF41878Fbf#tokentxns).

The USDC token address is 0x9FD21bE27A2B059a288229361E2fA632D8D2d074 which can be  seen from the transfer above.

This is the code for Dex.sol:

```
// contracts/FlashLoan.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import {IERC20} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/master/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";

contract Dex {
    address payable public owner;

    // Aave ERC20 Token addresses on Goerli network
    address private immutable daiAddress =
        0x75Ab5AB1Eef154C0352Fc31D2428Cef80C7F8B33;
    address private immutable usdcAddress =
        0x9FD21bE27A2B059a288229361E2fA632D8D2d074;

    IERC20 private dai;
    IERC20 private usdc;

    // exchange rate indexes
    uint256 dexARate = 90;
    uint256 dexBRate = 100;

    // keeps track of individuals' dai balances
    mapping(address => uint256) public daiBalances;

    // keeps track of individuals' USDC balances
    mapping(address => uint256) public usdcBalances;

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        dai = IERC20(daiAddress);
        usdc = IERC20(usdcAddress);
    }

    function depositUSDC(uint256 _amount) external {
        usdcBalances[msg.sender] += _amount;
        uint256 allowance = usdc.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allowance >= _amount, "Check the token allowance");
        usdc.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    }

    function depositDAI(uint256 _amount) external {
        daiBalances[msg.sender] += _amount;
        uint256 allowance = dai.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allowance >= _amount, "Check the token allowance");
        dai.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    }

    function buyDAI() external {
        uint256 daiToReceive = ((usdcBalances[msg.sender] / dexARate) * 100) *
            (10**12);
        dai.transfer(msg.sender, daiToReceive);
    }

    function sellDAI() external {
        uint256 usdcToReceive = ((daiBalances[msg.sender] * dexBRate) / 100) /
            (10**12);
        usdc.transfer(msg.sender, usdcToReceive);
    }

    function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "Only the contract owner can call this function"
        );
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Obvioussly this is the getBalance function that should return a value of `1000000` which is equal to 1 * 10^6 USDC but it just returns 0 in remix:

```
function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
    return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Everything was working fine before but i dont know what's gone wrong or am i an idiot. Thanks for any help!

i;m an idiot.. my remix environment was still RemixVM and not the injected.... funny how i realise that as soon as i ask the question after hours of no idea lol

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. Maybe you used a wrong contract or a wrong usdc address.

[image]